# How to get index value when user checked listview from alertdialog?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-alertdialog

How to get index value when user checked listview from android alertdialog

```
List<String> ShowView = new ArrayList<String>();
    final CharSequence[] Animals = ShowView.toArray(new String[ShowView.size()]);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TestActivity.this);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("ListView");
    dialogBuilder.setItems(Animals, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                                //This get index value!!
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alertDialogObject = dialogBuilder.create();
                        alertDialogObject.show();
```

Comment: Please update your question to make it clear exactly what you are trying to do - and your code so far. Put your code inside a comment block.

Comment: please provide a more complete question, instead of just dumping code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Int item is the index of clicked item .

```
 final CharSequence[] Animals= ShowView.toArray(new String[ShowView.size()]);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    builder.setTitle("ListView");
    builder.setItems(Animals, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
           String val=String.valueOf(Animals[item]);// this is value
        }
    });
    builder.show();
```

Comment: Thanks , I need it.

String val=String.valueOf(item); //0、1、2~n(index)

Comment: I gave you the answer as per my understanding. I think thats what you need . If you have more doubts Update you question with proper problem .

Answer (score 0):

the `int item` given from the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener()` is what you're looking for.